# Can we change the premise by using the contrapositive?

Tags: propositional-calculus

Can we change the premise by using the contrapositive?

For example, if we have $A \to (Q \land B)$. Say that $\neg (Q \land B) \to \neg A$, then start with the premise $\neg (Q \land B)$ and try to deduce $\neg A$.

Comment: If $A$ implies $Q$ and $B$, and you can show that at least one of $Q$ and $B$ is false, then clearly $A$ must be false. So you missed out the "not". Also it should be "deduce" not "deduct" (which means subtract).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $A \implies (Q \land B)$ and $\lnot (Q \land B) \implies \lnot A$ are equivalent statements. And by de Morgan this is further equivalent to $(\lnot Q \lor \lnot B) \implies \lnot A$. So yes.

But I cannot think of a situation where I'd prove a concrete statement that way.

In a formal deduction system you'd have some extra steps with this proof route:

- You could start with an assumption $A$.
- Then a subassumption $\lnot (Q \land B)$.
- deduce $\lnot A$ somehow.
- this contradicts the first assumption so we deduced $\lnot \lnot (Q \land B)$ and withdraw the subassumption (introduction rule for  $\lnot$).
- deduce $Q \land B$ by the double negation rule.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna prove a conditional $A \rightarrow B$ by proving the conditional $\neg B \rightarrow \neg A$, then what you wanna do is what is called a *proof by contrapositive*. This is a proof strategy very common among mathematicians, as Keith Devlin explain in his course [Introduction to Mathematical Thinking](https://www.coursera.org/learn/mathematical-thinking).